# .Net Framework (C#) Web Api file upload button exposed in Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, swagger

I'm working on a .Net Framework (NOT .Net Core) Web Api and need to implement a file upload endpoint in a controller, but not being able to do it exposing a file upload button in Swagger.

I'm using Swagger to test my API and I have a Swagger-Net 8.3 package installed, that's why I'd like to continue testing with Swagger and not with Postman (if possible).

I've been trying with many different methods implementations to no avail (never see an upload file button in Swagger interface). One example could be the next:

```
[HttpPost]
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData(IFormFile fileUpload)
 {
     // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
     if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
     {
         throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
     }

     string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
     var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

     try
     {
         // Read the form data.
         await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

         // This illustrates how to get the file names.
         foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
         {
             Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
             Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
         }
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     }
     catch (System.Exception e)
     {
         return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
     }
 }
```

And another example could be:

```
 [ValidateMimeMultipartContentFilter]
 [HttpPost, Route("softwarepackage")]
 public Task<GenericEntity> UploadSingleFile(IFormFile fileUpload)
 {

     var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider("ServerUploadFolder");
     var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith<GenericEntity>(t =>
     {
         var firstFile = streamProvider.FileData.FirstOrDefault();

         if (firstFile != null)
         {
             // Do something with firstFile.LocalFileName
         }

         return new GenericEntity
         {

         };
     });

     return task;
 }

public class FileOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
 public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
 {
     if (operation.operationId.ToLower() == "softwarepackage_uploadsinglefile")
     {
         if (operation.parameters == null)
             operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>(1);
         else
             operation.parameters.Clear();
         operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
         {
             name = "File",
             @in = "formData",
             description = "Upload software package",
             required = true,
             type = "file"
         });
         operation.consumes.Add("application/form-data");
     }
 }
}

public class ValidateMimeMultipartContentFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
 public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
 {
     if (!actionContext.Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
     {
         throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
     }
 }

 public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
 {

 }

}
```

But none of them displays an "Upload File" button in Swagger UI.

I've seen many implementations for a .Net Core Web Api, but any ideas on how to do it with a NON Core Web Api?